# Running a thermal camera (AMG8833) with an orange/raspberry pi but i2cdetect cannot detect any of the 2 cameras

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c, embedded, gpio, camera

I have bought 2 AMG8833 thermal cameras from different sellers. I tested both first with an orange pi zero and later with a raspberry pi zero. On the orange pi, I used the following GPIO pins and connected the camera with jumper cables, which do not hold well by themselves:

```
• Pin 1 (3.3 V) to VIN
• Pin 3 (SDA) to SDA
• Pin 5 (SCK) to SCL
• Pin 6 (GND) to GND
```

I then enabled i2c (rebooted) and i2cdetect did not give any output related to the camera. I then tested it with the raspberry pi, but still an empty output. Because it may be due to a loose contact, I soldered the 4 cables to the raspberry pi with the same result. After that, I noticed that the i2c pin 5 says SCK on the orange pi and SCL on the raspberry pi, although the manual of the orange pi zero says that the GPIO pins are equivalent to the raspberry pi models. Somewhere I read that SCK can **also** send data instead of only receiving it like SCL. Since I tested both cameras this way first, I wonder if this broke both of them or where the actual problem could be. On the pictures you can see the current setup with the raspberry pi and the second camera connected to the pins 1,3,5,9. I am also pretty sure that the camera receives power. Can you recommend some troubleshooting steps and things to watch out for?

Links:

I used [this](https://makersportal.com/blog/thermal-camera-analysis-with-raspberry-pi-amg8833) and similar guides.

[Raspberry pi zero GPIO](http://micro-pi.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Raspberry-Pi-Zero-V-1.2-GPIO.png) compared to [orange pi zero GPIO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fnkf.png):

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X83O9.jpg)

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjXsg.jpg)

Comment: Well, should the chip be detectable by i2cdetect? Not all chips use a protocol that allows i2cdetect to work with them, but I did not easily find a datasheet describing the protocol if it is compatible or not. If you can find the I2C protocol specs of the chip, please add that to your question.

Comment: I would try reading a register on the chip that you know what the value will be, that will establish communications. If you can't establish communications, you will need to troubleshoot the communications, preferably with a logic analyzer

Comment: Why have you not wired it  up as per the link you supplied? The AM8833 module has a regulator and level shifters so it runs on 5V. You connect it to 3V3.

Comment: @Kartman Because 5V would be regulated to 3V3 anyway. I tried that at the beginning.

Comment: That doesn’t make much sense. The board is intended to be run from 5V, so why violate that and create another potential problem?

Comment: @Kartman In the middle of the block text at the very beginning of the linked guide it says: "It also operates at 3.3V and 5V ..."  Or in this [datasheet](https://shop.as-electronic.net/download/panasonic/GridEye_Datasheet.pdf) it mentions both voltages. I think many single-board computers are equipped with a 5V output instead of 3V3 (if you cannot have both). This is what the regulator is for.

Comment: @Kartman And if I am not mistaken, it is a voltage range in which any voltage from 3V3 to 5V will be regulated to 3V3.

Comment: Rather than argue the minutiae, have you solved your problem? I’ve pointed out that you have wired yours differently to the example. Have you wired as per the example? Does it work?  Note in the datasheet it mentions both voltages - there’s a 5V part and a 3V3 part. The AM8833 is a 3V3 part. And you might very well be mistaken - make some voltage measurements to confirm.